# What am I doing wrong? (PHP/HTML submit button)

Tags: php

HTML:

```
<form action="?" method = "post" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name = "submit" value = 'Submit' >Register</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    ?>
```

The alerts don't come out when I click the button. The PHP does run if they're not enclosed within the 'if' statement.

Comment: closing tag issue `}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to close If tag.

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     echo '<script language="javascript">';
     echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
     echo '</script>';
   } 
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to include the if tag when CTRL+K'ing my code, but it's right there. That's not the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<script>alert('message successfully sent');</script>
<?php
}
?>

<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="submit" value="Register" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is there is **no closing tag for `if` function**

on here `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

and if your php code is **inside same page then** form action should be `action="#"` else if your php code **inside another file** `action` should be `action="new_oage.php"`

So code should be

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
        echo '</script>';
    } //Missing

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change your if condition...because you have no input field in form

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 
}
```